# libudev udev_device_get_sysattr_value() return NULL for idVendor/idProduct when device is removed

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I'm trying to implement USB monitor service/daemon to detect specfic PID/VID device only. I can easily detect device 'add' action attrib by filtering PID/VID but when I remove ANY USB device from port then as part of 'remove' action attrib, I try to filter PID/VID same like in 'add' action ... by using

```
const char* vendor = udev_device_get_sysattr_value(dev, "idVendor");

const char* product = udev_device_get_sysattr_value(dev, "idProduct");
```

but in above two char ptr I always get NULL.
Due to this my remove action will execute for **all USB device which will remove from port**

Is their any other way in libudev API to detect specific device remove only ?

Comment: I got answer after searching inside libudev/systemd code and this API called     ... const char *udev_device_get_property_value() with "product" as key solve my problem

Comment: but with latest kernel version (UBUNTU 18.04, CentOS 7.6 with kernel version 5.0) are returning null for *udev_device_get_property_value() method. What is your Linux system and kernel version ?

Comment: For me calling: `udev_device_get_property_value(dev, "ID_VENDOR_ID");` and `udev_device_get_property_value(dev, "ID_MODEL_ID");` seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Once the USB device is at the "remove" action, `udev_device_get_sysattr_value(dev)` will return NULL in my experience. Even the prior "unbind" action is too late.

One way to detect the removal of a specific device is to store its dev node when it is inserted.

First, find the `udev_device*` you want to monitor by enumerating the devices (`struct udev_enumerate*`)(device already plugged in) and monitoring the "add" or "bind" action.
In those states, the `udev_device_get_sysattr_value` will return the correct strings as you have already seen. If the values match the ones for the device you want to monitor, retrieve its current dev node by calling `udev_device_get_devnode(dev)`. Store that dev node value (`strdup` to make a copy of it).

In the "unbind" or "remove" action, `udev_device_get_devnode(dev)` will still return the proper value as opposed to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value(dev, prop_name)`. Match the dev_node with the previously stored dev node to identify that the action applies to the device you are monitoring.

Note that the dev node will likely change every time the device is inserted.